# Linking to show view with Ruby in application.js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I dynamically generate the title of a video from the embedly API in my application.js file with:

```
$(this).parent().prepend('<p>'+ oembed.title + '<p>');
```

Bear in mind that code is taken out of context.

Now I want to make the title a link to that video's show view. However, I don't believe I have access to named routes in my application.js file. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a long way of going about it (hopefully someone else comes up with a better solution), but perhaps in the view where the title is being generated, you can include the URL to the show view in a `data-` attribute, generated by ERB (Or Haml or whatever). For example:

```
<div class="video">
  <whatever class="my_embedly_object" data-show-url="<%= video_path(@video) %>" />
</div>
```

Then you can access the `data-show-url` via Javascript in your `application.js` code and use it to generate the link.

```
url = $(this).attr('data-show-url');
$(this).parent().prepend('<p><a href="' + url + '">' + oembed.title + '</a></p>');
```

Comment: I implemented this exactly, and I'm generating a link with an undefined `href`. My js must not picking up the `data-` attribute, and I'm not sure why. If you need to here's my code: https://github.com/meltzerj/Dreamstill  The partial that contains the embedly object is `_show_video.html.erb` and the javascript is in `application.js`

Comment: Which page is the link not working on? I see it not working on `/videos` because `app/views/videos/_video.html.erb` doesn't have the `data-show-url` in it at all. The link on `/videos/:id` is working fine. See [my diff](https://github.com/BinaryMuse/Dreamstill/compare/master...fix).